# Adding more than one param in GET request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, angularjs

```
url: "../api/api.php? fxn:" + encodeURIComponent(getCatergories) & "jsn"= +encodeURIComponent{"code":"1"},


var app = angular.module('MyTutorialApp',[]);
app.controller("MainController", function($scope,$http){
    $scope.loadpeople= function()
    {
       $http
     .get({

        url: "../api/api.php",
        data:{
            fxn:getCategories,
            jsn:'{"code":"1"}'
        }

    })
    .success(function(data){
        console.log("SUCCESS");
        $scope.people = data;
    })
    }
});
```

This is the url , i need to append the param with the URL.  I know how to do it for one, can you please tell me how to do it for two parameters ?

Answer (score 3):

**Clarification:** The question was heavily modified and changed, not going to update my answer to reflect it to a "new" question.

The most easy and readable way is to assign the `data` parameter:

```
url: 'the URL',
data: {
    a: 'something',
    b: 'something else'
},
...
```

> data:
>
> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests

[Ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

But to answer your question, just put the `&` inside the string and fix the query string:

```
url: "../api/api.php?fxn=" + encodeURIComponent(getCatergories) +
                   "&jsn=" + encodeURIComponent('something')
```

Comment: var app = angular.module('MyTutorialApp',[]);
app.controller("MainController", function($scope,$http){
    $scope.loadpeople= function()
    {
       $http
     .get({

        url: "../api/api.php",
        data:{
            fxn:getCategories,
            jsn:'{"code":"1"}'
        }
        
    })
    .success(function(data){
        console.log("SUCCESS");
        $scope.people = data;
    })
    }
});

Comment: this is my code , how exactly to do it , i am using angular js.

Comment: @Cerebus1504. Great, so you're using AngularJS, not jQuery. You should at least know what framework and library you're using!

Comment: Yes i knew , i kinda got confused sir.

Comment: @Cerebus1504, You're sir the reason I stopped participating in stackoverflow. "kinda got Confused".

Comment: the url is missing in the request url

Comment: @Cerebus1504 please stop bugging me. Do your basic homework first